# Fix a prime $p$. Define a proper class $A$ and a 2-ary function $+$ such that $ (A,+)$ is an abelian group where all non-zero elements have order $p$.

Tags: set-theory

This is an exercise from Kunen’s Set Theory. The hint says for p=2 to consider the universe $V$ and the symmetric difference $a+b:=(a-b)\cup (b-a)$ such that $x+x=\emptyset$ , which I fully understand, but I fail to see how this hint helps with cases other than p=2…

Comment: You might want to represent the $+$ sign that you are defining by a different notation (rather than using the usual one). It might create confusion.

Comment: For $p=2$, this is the symmetric difference $a \triangle b$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak I’m just trying to stick to the way Kunen wrote the original exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the reminders about various typos guys, I’m a little drunk tonight and the original writing was a bit off, but I believe that all formats and notations should be clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is the class $A$ of all maps from some finite set to $\Bbb Z_p^*:=(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)\setminus\{0\}$, with the obvious addition when considering them as maps with finite support, from the universe to $\Bbb Z_p$:

Extend $f:I\to\Bbb Z_p^*$ and $g:J\to\Bbb Z_p^*$ by $0$ to define $F,G:I\cup J\to\Bbb Z_p$, and denote by $f+g$ the restriction of $F+G:I\cup J\to\Bbb Z_p$ to the subset of $I\cup J$ where it is non-zero.

Another solution is the class of all maps from some set (not necessarily finite) to $\Bbb Z_p^*$, with the addition defined similarly.

You can of course find other solutions inbetween, bounding the cardinality of the supports by some cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\kappa+\kappa=\kappa$ (i.e. any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, if you assume the axiom of choice).

Comment: I’m going to try to rephrase that— Let Z_p be the group we’re familiar with, let $A$ be the collection of all elements in sets of the form $Z_p^I$, with $I$ a finite set. $A$ is clearly a proper class. Next, define $+: A\to A$ to be as you’ve described in the answer. \emptyset, the identity, is the function from the empty set to $Z_p$. Am I correct?

Comment: Nearly but not exactly. $A$ is the collections of all maps from some finite set to $\Bbb Z_p\setminus\{0\}$. This is necessary for $+:A\times A\to A$ (not $A\to A$) to be defined nonambiguously.

Comment: Thanks. This is amazing because if we start from $F_2^{*}$, it’s the hint at a second glance.

Comment: Yes, if you take my "another solution" (where the supports can be any set)